# Reference Application Class from Project Library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I am trying to reference a class that is in my application (MainActivity.class) from my Android project library.

To give an outline of the structure, it appears as so:

ExampleApp (src/com.example.recorder):
--->MainActivity

then inside ExampleLibrary (src/main/src/com.example.library):
---> FragManage

so from within FragManage:

```
// Get FragManage's tag for reference.
String myTag = getTag();
MainActivity.setTagFragManage(myTag);
```

but in Android studio I receive the error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'MainActivity'
```

Is there a way to create a reference to the class from the library? Also, I cannot just hardcode the path to MainActivity as I share this library with a Free version of my app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be referencing the other way round, objects from the library should be referenced from the application.

Anyway, what you could do is to create an interface or a base class in your library and use that in the library code. Then in your main app you could write the implementation of the interface or a child class.